# OL3 layer.Tile ZIndex function not found

Tags: openlayers, wms

I am trying to set the Index of a wms layer called "landsat1". It draws on top by default, and I want to move it down the order. 
I have tried

```
landsat1.setZIndex(1)
```

But I get an error "function not found". 
Im using ol 3.11.0. According to the [api documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.0/apidoc/ol.layer.Tile.html#setZIndex), the function is experimental....but it doesn't seem to work for any version that has this function....other functions like landsat1.getProperties() works fine....why does this function not work? Or is there a better way to set the zindex om the wms layer?

Answer (score 0):

Moved question into GIS area. My appologies